Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity....Hibernate-5
pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mortal</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>HibernateDemo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.27.Final</version> <!-- Replace with the latest version -->
</dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version> <!-- or the version compatible with your project -->
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
</project>

hibernate.cfg.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhiber</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.mortal.hibernate.Student" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Student.java (Entity class)
package com.mortal.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    
    public Student(int id, String name, String city) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Student() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", city=" + city + "]";
    }   
    
}

App.java
package com.mortal.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Project Started!!!!!!!!");

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

        System.out.println(factory);

        // Creating student object...
        Student st = new Student(101, "John Cena", "New York");

        System.out.println(st);

        Session session = factory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(st);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();   
        factory.close(); 
    }
}

Tried changing the hibernate versions but not working....expected answer is updating the values in database table, but showing Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:
-using eclipse IDE
-MySQL 8.0.3
-Tried with some versions of h5 and h4

The issue you're facing might be because you do not have the @Table annotation in your Student entity class. This annotation is used to specify the table to which the entity class is mapped. If it's not provided, Hibernate will use the class name as the table name which might be different from what you have as a table name in the database.

Tried with @Table annotation, but still same error.

Thank you everyone, I solved it by just putting hibernate and mysql connector dependency at top in pom.xml, it's tricky but done
